# Как правильно оформить модели SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, архитектура, sqlalchemy, model

Попробую сформулировать вопрос.

Сейчас я изучаю Python и SQLAlchemy делая проект для себя. Создал таблицу `User`:

```
Model = declarative_base()

class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    nickname = Column(String)
    email    = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

Добавил туда несколько записей.

Допустим теперь я хочу проверить - существует ли какой либо пользователь с указанным email? Я делаю следующее:

```
bool(session.query(exists().where(User.email == email)).scalar())
```

Как по мне - этот код абсолютно не читаем. Поэтому я вынес его (и другие подобные функции работы с базой) в отдельный класс `Users`. И вызываю их по мере необходимости в логике приложения.

```
class Users:
    def exists(email):
        return bool(session.query(exists().where(User.email == email)).scalar())

    def add(nick, email, password):
        pass # Тут код

    def email_exists(email):
        pass # Тут код

    def update(id, nick, email, password):
        pass # Тут код
```

Теперь я хочу понять. Насколько я продвинулся в велосипедостроении? Как нужно делать "по хорошему"? Я открыл несколько проектов с открытым исходным кодом и не встретил там ничего подобного. Поэтому у меня закрадывается мысль, что это не совсем верный путь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я когда-то делал подобным образом. Как по мне - нормальная реализация методов моделей. 
Неплохим решением будет создать базовый класс, от которого можно наследовать другие модели, а в самих методах добавлять нужную логику.

Для своих нужд, работая с фреймворком Flask, написал такую такую штуковину:

```
from ._base import db
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError, InterfaceError
from flask import flash
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.event import listen
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import MapperExtension
from ..utils.redis import redis_store
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr
from pickle import dumps, loads

@as_declarative()
class BaseExtension(MapperExtension):

    def after_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        row = instance.query.filter_by(id = instance.id).first()
        payload = {'model': instance.__class__.__name__, 'data': instance.id, 'type': 'INSERT', 'row': row}
        redis_store.publish('realtime', dumps(payload))


    def after_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        row = instance.query.filter_by(id = instance.id).first()
        payload = {'model': instance.__class__.__name__, 'data': instance.id, 'type': 'UPDATE', 'row': row}
        redis_store.publish('realtime', dumps(payload))


    def after_delete(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        row = instance.query.filter_by(id = instance.id).first()
        payload = {'model': instance.__class__.__name__, 'data': instance.id, 'type': 'DELETE', 'row': row}
        redis_store.publish('realtime', dumps(payload))



class Base(db.Model):

    __abstract__ = True
    __mapper_args__ = { 'extension': BaseExtension() }

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())

    @classmethod
    def create(cls,**kwargs):
        c = cls(**kwargs)
        db.session.add(c)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created successfully!', 'success')
        except IntegrityError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created failed!' + u' IntegrityError', 'error')
        except InterfaceError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created failed!' + u' InterfaceError', 'error')
        return c


    def __repr__(self):
        mapper = inspect(self).mapper
        ent = []
        object_data = {col.key: getattr(self, col.key) if not col.key == 'created_at' and not col.key == 'password' and not col.key == 'modified_at' else None  for col in mapper.column_attrs}

        return "{0}".format(object_data)
```

Сейчас я вижу, сколько тут всего ненужного и неправильного, но во всяком случае, для саморазвития, это был хороший опыт.

Во-первых, те поля, которые повторяются во всех моделях (id, created_at, modified_al) описываются единожды.

Во-вторых, наследуемый create(), с обработкой некоторых исключений.

В-третьих, [события ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/deprecated.html) (мой метод реализации которых считается устаревшим) after_insert, after_update, after_delete обрабатываются, и данные отдаются в redis. Я это делал для "real-time" передачи данных (нотификации, обновления данных в дашборде и пр.)

В-четвёртых, `__repr__`, который так же универсален для всех моделей.

Так же, сюда можно добавить так называемый 'soft-delete', который позволит не удалять данные из БД насовсем, а так же методы, чтобы доставать из базы "не удалённые", все и только удалённые.

Кучу всего можно придумать при необходимости.

В конечном счёте, один раз реализованный базовый класс сэкономит много времени и места в моделях.

Comment: Вы говорите что делали так "когда-то", а сейчас как делаете?

Comment: Я возможно не правильно выразился.
Сейчас использую те же принципы, просто использую другие фреймфорки, а там другие ORM.
Я не знаю, насколько правилен такой подход, но он рабочий и сокращает количество кода в целом. 
Фактически, модели - это классы, а раз уж так, то наследование, в т.ч. множественное - нормальная практика. 

Ещё, можно поискать нужные Вам т.н. миксины, которые и представляют из себя готовые методы для моделей.

Comment: Повторяющиеся поля (id, created_at, modified_at), методы типа create, delete - использовать чуть ли не обязательно, __repr__ тоже, по поводу остального - зависит от ваших целей и задач. 
Важно не повторять свой код по нескольку раз. Если ваш подход позволяет не повторятся, и при этом работает и не уродлив - то всё в порядке. Думаю так :)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще подход то правильный в духе ОО, но как правило session - не стоит использовать в модели, тем более как у вас в примере глобальную переменную session, лучше тогда ее передавать в метод/свойство.

И в вашем примере есть некоторая неправильность на мой взгляд - методы указанные в примере должны быть classmethod - методами класса, ведь они не привязаны к экземпляру сущности

Я бы посоветовал вам по возможности вместо обычных свойств/методов делать гибридные - на всякий случай. Вдруг потом понадобится делать запросы используя кусок логики свойства в конечных запросах они порой повышают читаемость.