# Получение данных сокетами при получении данных в mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, сокет, flask

Работаю с flask, socketio, mysql.
Сокетами дёргаю данные из mysql, это работает. Однако при обновлении данных в бд, они не обновляются на сайте.
Что нужно сделать и как?
Flask:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/mcc')
def ws_conn():
    json_data = parsing.getData(mysql)
    emit('packet', {'json_data': json_data}, namespace='/mcc', broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mysql.init_app(app)
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0',)
```

Запрос в бд:

```
def getData(mysql):
    cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cur.execute('''select * from gprs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1''')
    data = list(cur.fetchall())
    mysql.connect().commit
    r = []
    for element in data:
       ....
    return r
```

Comment: @Arnial учитывая что socketio используется, сервер сам  клиенту обновление послать, если необходимо (emit()). Если MySQL db снаружи изменяется, то можно trigger написать, чтобы сервер об изменении уведомить (или просто в сервере фоновый цикл завести, который дату последнего изменения будет спрашивать у db и оповещать клиентов об изменениях).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы данные обновлялись на сайте без перезагрузки страниц, нужно чтобы эти данные и принимались и передавались на бэкенд при помощи `socketio`, и в идеале, нужен какой-то `pubsub`, можно `redis`.

[Здесь](https://rochard.org/personal-projects/extending-flask-admin-to-be-realtime/) отличный пример `realtime flask-admin`, правда на `postgres` и в роли `pubsub` выступает [pgpubsub](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgpubsub/0.0.4)

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-sqlalchemy/647315#647315) я привёл пример базовой модели. которая делает `pub` в `redis`.

Если нужно что-то подобное, то необходим сам `redis`, в который отдаёте данные из БД, какой-нибудь `eventlen` и несколько функций `soketio` при помощи которых данные принимаются из канала, и передаются в него.

Так же, нужно будет изменить шаблон и написать немного `js`.